# USO DE SED COM UMA VARIAVEL

Tags: linux

estou precisando configurar dois arquivos .sh, o primeiro arquivo sshpasssrv.sh vai ser responsavel por preencher o segundo arquivo que sera sshpass.sh, o primeiro arquivo quando executado, vai pedir o ip, então ele vai preencher o segudo arquivo com o ip que eu quero na seguinte linha de comando: sshapss -p "senha" ssh root@192.168.1.18 por exemplo, tenho mais ou menos a ideia que segue abaixo, preciso que preencher o segundo arquivo so com o ip.

```
#!/bin/bash   
#Aki pega o que digitar e coloca na variavel sshpass

echo "IP DO ARQUIVO SSHPASS :"
read ip

# Aki ele nao faz nada + do que a saida do comando echo $ip ele coloca no arquivo sshpass.sh

echo $ip >> sshpass.sh
sed "sshpass -p "pdvlinux" "$ip sshpassh.sh
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se eu entendi o que você quer fazer. Que seria, adicionar um comando no arquivo sshpassh.sh baseado no IP que foi informado.
Você não precisa adicionar o IP e depois dar um sed para alterar a linha.

Altere as duas ultimas linhas do seu código para:

```
echo "sshpass -p \"senha\" ssh root@$ip" >> sshpassh.sh
```

Se quiser sempre substituir o comando que já estava definido no arquivo, troque de >> para >.

Dica: Não seria melhor fazer o ssh com chave privada/estrangeira ao invés de utilizar o sshpass?

Comment: no caso usando ssh com chave privada/estrangeira ficaria como?
qual a sua sugestão?

Comment: @RicardoJMSistemas Antes vc tem que criar uma chave pública/privada na maquina cliente com o comando ssh-keygen. Ai vc copia o conteúdo do arquivo .pub criado na pasta ~/.ssh para o arquivo ~/.ssh/authorized_keys do seu servidor. Com isso vc deve conseguir logar no servidor a partir do seu cliente fazendo apenas um "ssh root@$ip" não precisa passar a senha. Esse [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/como-configurar-chaves-ssh-no-ubuntu-18-04-pt) tem um passo a passo com imagens para facilitar.